# Skip parts while reading and writing a file in Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn Java/Android and right now I'm doing some experiments with the `replaceAll` function. But I've found that with large text files the process gets sluggish so I was wondering if there is a way to skip the "useless" parts of a file to have a better performance. (Note: Just skip them, not delete them)

Note: I am not trying to "count lines" or "println" or "system.out", I'm just replacing strings and saving the changes in the same file.

***Example***

**AAAA**

**CCCC-** 9234802394819102948102948104981209381'238901'2309'129831'2381'2381'23081'23081'284091824098304982390482304981'20841'948023984129048'1489039842039481'204891'29031'923481290381'20391'294872385710239841'20391'20931'20853029573098341'290831'20893'12894093274019799919208310293810293810293810293810298'120931¿2093¿12039¿120931¿203912¿0391¿203912¿039¿12093¿12093¿12093¿12093¿12093¿1209312¿0390¿... **DDDD**

**AAAA**

**CCCC-** 9234802394819102948102948104981209381'238901'2309'129831'2381'2381'23081'23081'284091824098304982390482304981'20841'948023984129048'1489039842039481'204891'29031'923481290381'20391'294872385710239841'20391'20931'20853029573098341'290831'20893'12894093274019799919208310293810293810293810293810298'120931¿2093¿12039¿120931¿203912¿0391¿203912¿039¿12093¿12093¿12093¿12093¿12093¿1209312¿0390¿... **DDDD**

**and so on....like a zillion times**

I want to replace all **"AAAA"** with **"BBBB"**, but there are large portions of data between the strings I am replacing. Also, this portions always begin with **"CCCC"** and end with **"DDDD"**.

Here's the code I am using to replace the string.

```
File file = new File("my_file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = "", oldtext = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   oldtext += line + "\r\n";
}
reader.close();

// Replacing "AAAA" strings
String newtext= oldtext.replaceAll("AAAA", "BBBB");

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("my_file.txt");
writer.write(newtext);
writer.close();
```

I think reading all lines is inefficient, especially when you won't be modifying these parts (and they represent the 90% of the file).

Does anyone know a solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wasting a lot of time on this line --

```
oldtext += line + "\r\n";
```

In Java, `String` is immutable, which means you can't modify them.  Therefore, when you do the concatenation, Java is actually making a complete copy of `oldtext`. So, for every line in your file, you are recopying every line that came before in your new `String`.  Take a look at [`StringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for a a way to build a `String` avoiding these copies.

However, in your case, you do not need the whole file in memory, because you can process line by line.  By moving your `replaceAll` and `write` into your loop, you can operate on each line as you read it. This will keep the memory footprint of the routine down, because you are only keeping a single line in memory.

Note that since the `FileWriter` is opened before you read the input file, you need to have  a different name for the output file.  If you want to keep the same name, you can do a [`renameTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) on the `File` after you close it.

```
File file = new File("my_file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("my_out_file.txt");
String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Replacing "AAAA" strings
    String newtext= line.replaceAll("AAAA", "BBBB");    
    writer.write(newtext);
}
reader.close();
writer.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This one performs much faster than my original code. But then I must assume that there is no way to avoid reading the whole file.

Comment: @user2012897  Generally that is true, you can't. Because you do not know how many bytes long the lines are actually going to be until you've ready them.